# SqlException not passing a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a handler class file, a default page and a master page.
The default page instantiates an instance of the handler class, and the handler then does all the communication with the database.
The master page contains a label that is supposed to display error outputs, passed to it from the handler via the default page. This is done via the following:

*Handler:*

```
catch (SqlException e)
     {
        errorString = e.ToString();
     }
```

*Default.aspx.cs:*

```
errorString = handler.errorString;
((SiteMaster)Master).getErrorLabel.Text = errorString;
```

*Site.Master.cs:*

```
public Label getErrorLabel
    {
        get { return this.errorLabel; }
    }
```

When I pass a value that doesn't match any record in my database, the errorString continues to hold `null`. Am I doing something wrong?

*edit: I have also tried `e.Message` and `e.Message.ToString()` without success*

Comment: So the `errorString` is a member of the class? Is the class a singleton?

Comment: Side-Note: instead of exposing the whole label i would only use it's `Text` property, but with getter and setter. On this way you reduce the chance of bugs and you could also change the implementation without breaking the code(f.e. use a `TextBox`).

Comment: @YoryeNathan errorString is a separately defined string. I deemed it unimportant to include.

Comment: @Wolfish Where is the variable defined?

Comment: What happens in the `try` statement here? Are you sure an empty result set raises an SqlException? Not sure that is necessarily an exceptional case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Um... do you mean `return this.errorLabel.Text`?

Comment: @Wolfish: yes, and `this.errorLabel.Text = value;`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Wherever a method uses `errorString`, it is defined at the beginning of my class, prior to any methods.

Comment: @glenatron Really? I didn't know this. What constitutes as an exception then? Is there a list of documented exceptions anywhere?

Comment: @Wolfish - Depends what is happening in your code, you could raise it directly, but if the database didn't exist, you had a bad ConnectionString or you passed in malformed SQL.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can't do that, I can't access _Default.aspx.cs from Site.Master.cs. Also, textboxes are ugly.

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood me completely. My code is sitting in the property of the master and the textbox was just an example of a different implementation in your master. You could even use the session or database. My comment was just meant to be as improvement not solution.

Comment: Making a member named `errorString` in all classes doesn't mean it is the same variable - it is not. Make sure you access the correct variable and that it is defined the the correct scope.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Please re-read the snippets. I clearly specify a chain, where `errorLabel` gets a value from the class underneath or inside the current working class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not sure exactly what you meant, you're clearly much more knowledgeable about it than I (I've only worked with C# for a few months). I did, however, solve this issue, and I'll post it below as soon as I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch() specifies an SQLException class.  If the exception thrown is not of that type, then the actual exception is not handled.  Try changing that to the base Exception class and see what you get.  It's probably an error being thrown from somewhere else in the code.